# How does this asm code setup SEH?

Tags: exception, assembly, x86, masm, seh

I grabbed some [code from internet](http://www.winasm.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=2082), that supposed to handle exceptions with SEH,

```
  ASSUME FS:NOTHING
  PUSH  OFFSET Handler
  PUSH  FS:[0]
  MOV  FS:[0], ESP
  ...
```

But the `FS:[0]` should be holding the address of handler instead right?

So `mov fs:[0], esp` is wrong, because `esp` currently pointed to the original `fs:[0]`:

The stack is like this:

```
-----------
| fs:[0]  |  <-- ESP
-----------
| handler |
-----------
```

So, shouldn't that be `esp + 4` like stuff? I'm obviously wrong, but I don't get why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[fs:0]` points to the last element in the linked list of exception handlers.

Each element contains two things:

1. the address of the next/previous element
2. the address of a handler/function

The code that you presented creates another element, links it to the current/last element, and makes the new element the current/last one.

Look up Matt Pietrek's articles on SEH. This stuff is described there in greater detail.

Comment: Also, don't manually modify the TEB like this, but use the appropriate API functions instead.